# Weird CSS issue involving inline overrides in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, inline

http://searchdatacenter.techtarget.com/informationCenter/0,296712,sid80_iid371,00.html

On this page the ad on the bottom right with the black background header doesn't pickup the inline styles in IE.  So it's the custom grey and black text in IE but the correct black background and white text in Firefox.

The default styles come from a stylesheet....the overrides come inline.  Any reason why this isn't being picked up by IE?

Edit: Thanks, missed the overrides come inlinedoctype. Any reason why this isn't being picked up by IE?

Comment: Quirks mode + proprietary `<html XMLNS:IE>` = RUN.

Comment: I hope this is not your website... Chrome comes across 18 major rendering errors. I wont elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

The style tag is only valid inside the head section of the page, and the linked stylesheet just above it should be in the head as well. You're lucky what you have works in anything.

If this is difficult to change, your best bet is probably removing your style block and using the style attribute on the div instead:

```
<div class="cltHeader" style="background-color: black;">
```